# Sharing VHD with a specific Azure accounts

Tags: azure

We have beta software we want to make available to select customers, and unlike AWS, this ability does not seem possible.  Is it possible to create a custom VHD, upload it to Azure, and share it ONLY with specific Azure accounts?

Comment: Just want to share VHD to customers? or create a VM and share this VM to customers? In Azure, we can create a resource group and create a `RBAC` rule to make someone can find this VM or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific option is not available.

However, an alternative (you probably already thought of this) would be to provide each user with a VM of their own, with your software running.

Or, create one VM with with the software running, and ask your users to test it at specific times.

Or, see if you can publish it as a web app, if thats an option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In my situation, running VM's for each of my customers to test beta SW would be expensive.  With AWS, this is simple.  I just need to know the customer ID for the AWS instance.  This is disappointing, which seems to be the case with Azure often.